# How to group ModX Revolution GalleryAlbums by year

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

How is it possible to group albums by year?

For example:

```
2014
- Album 1
- Album 2

2013
- Album 3
```

I've recently [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27236582/edit) that it is possible to group them in the backend using a subfolder-like approach to sort them - but is it also possible to query albums for a specific folder?

I'm currently using this call in my Gallery overview:

```
[[!GalleryAlbums? &sort=`year` &albumCoverSort=`random`  &rowTpl=`galAlbumRowTpl`
                  &toPlaceholder=`galleries` &showAll=`1` &parent=`6`
                  &prominentOnly=`0` &limit=`50`]]
<div class="galleries">[[+galleries]]</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the GalleryAlbums Snippet doesn't support sorting by year, even though there's a "year" field for the Album object:

[image: MODX Gallery Album Edit View]

However, there's a couple ways to do this.

**1. Write your own Snippet**

This would be the most performant option, but instructions for this might be out of scope here, so another option might be:

**2. Nested Template Chunks**

Organize your albums by nesting them under parent albums named after the year. So you'd have an album called "2014" and under that you'd have child albums you want to display for that year.

Then modify your snippet call to include these properties:

```
&showAll=`0`
&parent=`0`
```

According to the [Gallery documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/gallery/gallery.galleryalbums), this is what those properties do:

- showAll  If 1, will show all albums regardless of their parent.
- parent   Grab only the albums with a parent album with this ID. Remember to set showAll to 0, otherwise it won't work!

Now modify your rowTpl, so that it's something like this:

```
<li>[[+name]]
    <ul>[[GalleryAlbums? &showAll=`0` &parent=`[[+id]]` ... ]]</ul>
</li>
```

What this means, is that your "outer" Snippet call gets only "top-level" albums, because you specified that the parent attribute must be "0". Then the tpl for each album calls the Gallery snippet again, with the parent property as the ID of the currently iterated Album, thereby returning a list of child Albums. Note in the above code sample, I've omitted the other important properties like &rowTpl, which you would need to populate.

NOTE: I see you're calling your Snippet with the uncached token `!`. You might get performance gains by caching it, especially if you use an aggressive caching mechanism like [StatCache](http://modx.com/extras/package/statcache). Granted the GalleryAlbums getList processor utilizes its own cache handler, but there will likely be performance penalties for using a nested Snippet call like the one I've described here.

Comment: That looks promising! But I assume this solution (referring to nested template chunks) implies, that I cannot show all the years (sub galleries) on one page, right? Otherwise, how can I reference the correct `[[+galleries]]` block?

Comment: Yes, you can show all the albums on one page—that's what this setup is meant to do. The `[[+galleries]]` placeholder is populated by the outer GalleryAlbums snippet call. The "nested" calls return their values directly into the tpl Chunk being iterated for the top-level album. Unless of course you set the `&toPlaceholder` property, but that's optional .